# ngx-quill and Quill resize module breaking Jasmine tests

Tags: angular, jasmine, ngx-quill

I am using ngx-quill with the image-resize-module and have it working in my app

```
import Quill from 'quill';
import ImageResize from 'quill-image-resize-module';
Quill.register('modules/imageResize', ImageResize);

export class MyComponent {

  quillModules = {
    imageResize: {},
    toolbar: [
      ...
    ],
  };
}
```

And in my angular.json I have added quill.js to the scripts in both build and test

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.min.js",
]
```

My test file is importing QuillModule

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      QuillModule,
      ...
    ],
```

However, in my jasmine tests, I am getting this warning

> 'quill', 'Overwriting modules/imageResize with', function t(e){ ... }

and this error

```
{
  "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\n[object ErrorEvent]",
  "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\n[object ErrorEvent]"
}
```

This is breaking my whole test runner, it only runs about 40 tests before throwing this error.
I narrowed it down to registering the imageResize module in my component

```
Quill.register('modules/imageResize', ImageResize);
```

If I remove this line, my tests work again.

#### Edit

I have found a fix and added the answer

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled across a fix after reading this [github post](https://github.com/kensnyder/quill-image-resize-module/issues/16#issuecomment-392150611)

Instead of importing Quill I imported QuillNameSpace and defined Quill as QuillNameSpace.

```
import * as QuillNamespace from 'quill';
import ImageResize from 'quill-image-resize-module';
const Quill: any = QuillNamespace;
Quill.register('modules/imageResize', ImageResize);
```